# Window Function For Consecutive Dates

Tags: amazon-redshift, window-functions

I want to know how many users were active for 3 consecutive days *on any given day*.
e.g on 2022-11-03, 1 user (user_id = 111) was active 3 days in a row. Could someone please advise what kind of window function(?) would be needed?

**This is my dataset:**

| user_id | active_date |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2022-11-01 |
| 111 | 2022-11-02 |
| 111 | 2022-11-03 |
| 222 | 2022-11-01 |
| 333 | 2022-11-01 |
| 333 | 2022-11-09 |
| 333 | 2022-11-10 |
| 333 | 2022-11-11 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are confident there are no duplicate user_id + active_date rows in the source data, then you can use two LAG functions like this:

```
SELECT user_id,
       active_date,
       CASE WHEN DATEADD(day, -1, active_date) = LAG(active_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY active_date)
             AND DATEADD(day, -2, active_date) = LAG(active_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY active_date)
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
       END AS rowof3
FROM your_table
ORDER BY user_id, active_date;
```

If there might be duplication, use this FROM clause instead:

```
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, active_date :: DATE FROM your_table)
```